# Как работает буфер обмена в LXDE?

Tags: linux

Когда я копирую в командную строку какое-нибудь слово, то у меня вместо строки word вставляется строка 0~word1~

а иногда вставляется ^[[200~word^[[201~

почему так происходит?

В интернете пишут:
"something has enabled 'bracketed paste mode' on your terminal. gnome-terminal (and based on it terminator) does not handle it currently well"

мне не ясно что это за режим такой, где он описан и как его отключить.

Comment: Буфер обмена — это не фича линукса. Это фича оконной системы (например, KDE или Gnome), или X Window, или программ наподобие `screen`. Так что вам придётся описать свою среду и то, как именно вы работаете с буфером обмена.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался - 

http://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste 

To disable the bracketed paste mode:

```
printf "\e[?2004l"
```